# this.objectName in a bigger object becomes undefined during execution

Tags: javascript, oop

I create a project with HTML Canvas and it works well. At the beginning it was something like:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Line(x, y, context, length, speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.ctx = context;
    this.length = length;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.isDrawingNow = false;
    this.initialCoordinates = {
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y
    }
    console.log(this.initialCoordinates);

    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);

    this.draw = function() {
        this.ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
        this.ctx.stroke();
    }

    this.updateRight = function() {
        this.x += this.speed;
        this.draw();
    }

    // Same functions as the above one, but for the other directions
}

let line = new Line(50, 50, ctx, 30, 1);

function animateRight() {
    if (line.initialCoordinates.x + line.length <= canvas.width) {
        line.isDrawingNow = true;
        if (line.x < line.initialCoordinates.x + line.length) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animateRight);
            line.updateRight();
        } else {
            line.initialCoordinates.x = line.x;
            line.isDrawingNow = false;
        }
    }
}

// Same functions as the above one, but for left, up, down directions

window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown); // Event listener for the arrow keys

function keyDown(e) {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft' && !line.isDrawingNow) {
        animateLeft();
    } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight' && !line.isDrawingNow) {
        animateRight();
    // the other keys
    }
}
```

Then I considered I have to include the animateRight() (animateDirection functions) in the Line object. I did so:

```
// Same as the old object plus:
this.animateRight = function() {
    console.log(this.initialCoordinates);
    if (this.initialCoordinates.x + this.length <= canvas.width) {
        this.isDrawingNow = true;
        if (this.x < this.initialCoordinates.x + this.length) {
            requestAnimationFrame(this.animateRight);
            this.updateRight();
        } else {
            this.initialCoordinates.x = this.x;
            this.isDrawingNow = false;
        }
    }
}

// The other directions...
// Now I have to call the animateDirection on arrowkey press like this (line is the new Line): 

function keyDown(e) {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft' && !line.isDrawingNow) {
        line.animateLeft();
    } else if (e.key === 'ArrowRight' && !line.isDrawingNow) {
        line.animateRight();
}
```

Unfortunately, the new code doesn't work, when I press right arrow, I get the error "this.initialCoordinates is undefined". I used the firefox debugger to find the problem. I saw that animateRight is called once, the the requestAnimationFrame recalls animateRight again, but this time this.initialCoordinates is undefined, same for this.length so the program stops. I don't understand what't the problem. Please help me! I'm new to OOP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I JavaScript, the value of `this` depends of how the function is called. If the function is called like a method, `obj.func()`, `this` will be `obj`. If the function is called normally, `func()`, `this` will be `undefined` (or the global object in non-strict mode).

You are passing a function (`this.animateRight`) to `requestAnimationFrame`, which it calls like a normal function, so inside it, `this` doesn't work properly.

In the old days of JS, this was commonly solved by assigning `this` to a variable (usually called `self`). However, there are better ways to solve the problem now:

### 1. [Arrow funtions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Arrow functions are an exception to the rules above mentioned for `this`. They take the value from the scope in which they were defined.

```js
// [...]
if (this.x < this.initialCoordinates.x + this.length) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.animateRight();
    });
    this.updateRight();
} else {
// [...]
```

### 2. [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

The `bind` method of functions returns a new function which will call the function with the specified value of `this`. (Binds `this` in a function to a specified value.)

```js
// [...]
if (this.x < this.initialCoordinates.x + this.length) {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animateRight.bind(this));
    this.updateRight();
} else {
// [...]
```

This method is not as flexible as arrow functions, because you can only call one function directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, arrow functions were just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Store a pointer in to the class itself as a variable in the class and use it inside the inner function instead of `this`, because `this` inside the inner function refers to the function itself not the class:

```js
function Line(x, y, context, length, speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.ctx = context;
    this.length = length;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.isDrawingNow = false;
    this.initialCoordinates = {
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y
    }
    console.log(this.initialCoordinates);

    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);

   var self = this; // <------------------------ HERE
   this.draw = function() {
        self.ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
        self.ctx.stroke();
    }

    this.updateRight = function() {
        self.x += this.speed;
        self.draw();
    }

    // Same functions as the above one, but for the other directions
}
```